# How to effectively loop variables in univariate analysis?

Tags: r, dataframe, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival

I have written below code to run cox regression and output them to a table. I want to run univariate on many variables. Can you help me to use a loop to make it faster. variables are Grade, DCIS, LVE, Tsize and so on ...

The code I have written is below:

```
CoxphToDF <- function(y) {
    stopifnot(class(y) == "summary.coxph")
    cbind(y[["coefficients"]], 
          `lower 0.95` = y[["conf.int"]][, "lower .95"], 
          `upper 0.95` = y[["conf.int"]][, "upper .95"])
          }

Grade <- data[!is.na(data$Grade) & data$Grade != "", ]
df1 = CoxphToDF(summary(coxph(Surv(OS, OS.Event) ~ Grade, data = Grade)))

DCIS <- data[!is.na(data$DCIS) & data$DCIS != "", ]
df2 = CoxphToDF(summary(coxph(Surv(OS, OS.Event) ~ DCIS, data = DCIS)))

LVE <- data[!is.na(data$LVE) & data$LVE != "", ]
df3 = CoxphToDF(summary(coxph(Surv(OS, OS.Event) ~ LVE, data = LVE)))

Tsize <- data[!is.na(data$Tsize) & data$Tsize != "", ]
df4 = CoxphToDF(summary(coxph(Surv(OS, OS.Event) ~ Tsize, data = Tsize)))

write.table(rbind(df1,df2,df3,df4), "univariate_results.txt", sep="\t", col.names = NA)
```

I have tried the following:

```
#vector of variables
variables_to_test <- c("Grade", "DCIS", "LVE", "Tsize")

#list to store the results
results_list <- list()

# Iterate
for (variable in variables_to_test) {
  subset_data <- data[!is.na(data[[variable]]) & data[[variable]] != "", ]
  result <- CoxphToDF(summary(coxph(Surv(OS, OS.Event) ~ ., data = subset_data)))
  results_list[[variable]] <- result
}

# single data frame
results_df <- do.call(rbind, results_list)
```

It gives me unexpected results with all variables in the dataframe but not selected and weird results

Comment: Hi, you may want to have a look at the functions `apply()`, `lapply()` and the package `purrr`. If you need more help, please provide a reproducible example (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Also, what do you mean as "effective" is it in a computation-time perspective?

Comment: @Paul added an example dataset

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `lapply()`?

```
#vector of variables
variables_to_test <- c("Grade", "DCIS", "LVE", "Tsize")

do.call(what = "rbind", 
        args = lapply(X = variables_to_test, 
                      FUN = \(x) {
                        data <- data[!is.na(data[[x]]) 
                                     & data[[x]] != "", ]
                        CoxphToDF(summary(coxph(Surv(OS, OS.Event) ~ ., data = data)))
                      }
                      )
        )
```

Be aware that each model fitting issues a warning

```
1: In coxph.fit(X, Y, istrat, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  :
  Ran out of iterations and did not converge
```

I see no advantages in `do.call(what = "rbind", args = something)`. Consider storing the results in a list, i.e., `list_of_sth <- lapply(...`.